# The usage of the definite article in "she ran like the wind to catch up"

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles

> She ran like **the** wind to catch up.

The above is an example from the Cambridge dictionary. What does "the" suggest here? Is it correct and idiomatic to use no article at all before "wind" in the example? Also, is it idiomatic to use the article "a" before "wind" in that example?'

My assumption is that ***the wind*** in the example = "the wind that is around them at that moment", am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Like the wind' is an idiomatic phrase meaning 'very fast'. You need the definite article. Using an indefinite article, or no article, would be incorrect. Regard 'the wind' to mean 'any generic fast-blowing wind'. There does not need to be a wind blowing at the time.

[Like the wind (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/like_the_wind)